# Check elements if already exist in Linked List C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

We have a assignment to write a function which add items in the list display the items in the list. Then if the elements already exist it should print data already exist.

I tried adding if statement below `if(displayPointer != NULL)` but it's always true. How can i compare my previous list to my new list and check if they have same or different data?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main()
{
    struct List
    {
        string name = "";
        int gpa;
        double courseHours;
        List *prev;
        List *next;
    };

    List *head;
    head = NULL;

    string inpName = "";
    int inpAge;
    List *newList;
    List *nextListPointer;
    List *prevListPointer;

    for(int ctr = 1; ctr <= 3; ctr++)
    {
        cout << "\nEnter name" << ctr << ": ";
        cin >> inpName;
        cout << "Enter age" << ctr << ": ";
        cin >> inpAge;


        if (head == NULL)
        {
            newList = new List;
            newList->name = inpName;
            newList->gpa = inpAge;
            newList->prev = NULL;
            newList->next = NULL;

            head = newList;
            prevListPointer = head;
        }
        else
        {
            nextListPointer = new List;
            nextListPointer->name = inpName;
            nextListPointer->gpa = inpAge;
            nextListPointer->prev = prevListPointer;
            nextListPointer->next = NULL;
            prevListPointer->next = nextListPointer;

            prevListPointer = nextListPointer;
        }
    }

    List *displayPointer;
    displayPointer = head;

    if (displayPointer == NULL)
    {
        cout << "no node to display" << endl;
    }

    // i tried adding if statement here but its always true
    if (head == displayPointer)  
    {
        cout << "\nData is already in the list!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while (displayPointer != NULL)
        {
            cout << "\nData stored is " << endl;
            cout << "Name : " << displayPointer->name << endl;
            cout << "Age  : " << displayPointer->gpa << endl;
            cout << " at " << displayPointer << endl;

            displayPointer = displayPointer->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You know that line is _outside_ the `for` loop, right? And you assigned `displayPointer = head` before that line? Did you expect `head` to be `NULL` after the loop completes?

Comment: Your question implies you have 2 separate lists to compare. But the code you have shown only has 1 list.  And the code is just comparing pointers.  To find if a particular item already exists in a list, you should compare the *contents* of the items instead. For instance, compare the `name` fields, which should uniquely identify each item.

Comment: *"I tried adding if statement below `if(displayPointer != NULL)`"* -- Where is this statement in your code? I do see an `if` statement that checks for equality and a `while` statement that checks for inequality, but not an `if` statement that checks for inequality.

Comment: Your code would be easier to debug if you broke it into functions. Trying to do everything in the `main` function leads to less readable and more bug-prone code. Plus, if you test each function individually, you should be able to drastically reduce the size of your [mre] without much additional effort.

Comment: `if (newList->name == nextListPointer->name && newList->gpa == nextListPointer->gpa)` i tried this and its working if i need to add only 2 elements. If i add 3 elements and 2 of those are same it still print the 3 elements even the 2 element are same. It should stop printing i input 2 same elements

Comment: @CodeApollo you have to write the comparisons for as many elements (did you mean fields instead?) as you need. The code will only do what you tell it to do.

Comment: Can i compare the fields instead? i only did so this `if (newList->name == nextListPointer->name && newList->gpa == nextListPointer->gpa)` if i add new element i will also add new condition to compare.